# How can I check type constraints within a pattern

Tags: rust, type-level-computation

I'm currently having fun doing some with macros and type-level programming in Rust, so my question here is more of a "how far can I push Rust in this direction?" rather than "please help me or my program is never going to work".

## What I'd like to do

I'm writing a pattern macro and I'd like to introduce type constraints within that macro.

For instance:

```rust
trait FooBar {
   const TAG: &'static str;   
}

match foo { // foo implements `FooBar`
   my_macro!{x, y, z} => ...
 | ...
}
```

I would like `my_macro!` to cause a compile-time error if, for instance, `foo::TAG` is not `"ACCEPTABLE"`.

## Why would you want to do that?

I'm writing [a few macros that implement anonymous structs in Rust](https://github.com/Yoric/obstruct-rs). It's a proof of concept, in an attempt to (hopefully) show that we do not need deep changes in the type system to implement anonymous structs and named arguments in the language.

In my current implementation, type-safety relies upon these `TAG` fields. It works if we're willing to rewrite the expression side of pattern matches, to perform these type-level shenanigans, but that makes the macros much more complicated and brittle. I'm looking for a better way to perform the same checks.

I'm ok with restricting myself to Rust Nightly.

Comment: Patterns don't run code and don't provide a foundation where new items can be introduced (i.e. the `const _: () = {}` trick could be used in many other contexts). The only way I could see doing that kind of thing within a `match` would be with a *match guard*, though I'm not sure if that expansion is valid. It doesn't seem to be with a declarative macro ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=571c98e33d0e6dd2b4321ffbb5dfc21d)), but maybe it is with a procedural macro. And even so, that wouldn't be composable with other patterns.

Comment: Yeah, with a match guard I could run arbitrary code, but I don't think I can introduce an irrefutable match guard.

I have also looked at `const` patterns but I haven't found a good way to make use of them for my purpose.